# Vue.js dynamic class name?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need a color degradation depending on a review grade. I was hoping to get something done in Vue.js like so:

```
<div class="review" :style="reviewColor(hotel.average)">
```

And in my methods I have something like this:

```
reviewColor() {
    return 'green';
}
```

Unfortunately this does not provide me with a `'green'` class. I was hoping to do my color calculation in the method.

If the grade is less than a 7 it needs to be a specific color, if between 7 and 8 and higher than 8.

I need these calculations in a clean matter. Is there any alternative?

I can't inline it because I have 2 elements that need to respond to a class.

Comment: You need to specify the style aspect that you want to change. `style="green"` isn't valid. Try  `:style="{color:reviewColor(hotel.average)}"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Unfortunately this does not provide me with a 'green' **class**.

You need to bind to `class`, not `style`:

```html
<div class="review" :class="reviewColor(hotel.average)">
```

```js
reviewColor(grade) {
  if (grade < 7) {
    return 'red';
  } else if (grade < 9) {
    return 'yellow';
  } else {
    return 'green';
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. That's what you get when you do a quick re-factor. Solved everything in 46 seconds. Haha thanks!