# How to add a class conditionally in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a project that I'm converting to Vue, and I was wondering how I can conditionally add a class to certain elements depending on what is returned from the database and rendered with Vue. Here is the code I had for the application when I was not using Vue:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.task_element').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).find(".task_priority").text().trim() === "high") {
      $(element).addClass('high');
    } else if ($(element).find(".task_priority").text().trim() === "medium") {
      $(element).addClass('medium');
    } else if ($(element).find(".task_priority").text().trim() === "low") {
      $(element).addClass('low');
    }
  });
});
```

And this worked fine. But, I'm wondering is there a way to do this with Vue much more easily? Or would I have to find a way to throw this into my Vue app?

Here is part of the component:

```
<p class="task_description">
  {{ task.description }} <span class="badge badge-pill">priority</span>
</p>
<p class="task_priority">
  {{ task.priority }}
</p>
```

What I want to do is bind the style of the badge (add one of the classes, either high, medium, or low) based on the value of the `task_priority` element. How would I achieve this?

Comment: can you share with as your component, please ?

Comment: generally, we use vuejs computed properties for this.

Comment: I've updated my question with the part of the component related to the issue

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145261/vue-js-dynamic-class-name

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With Vue class binding, you can do this right inline on the element and actually add an additional Vue computed class to your already defined class list.

for example:

```
<div class="task_priority" :class="task.priority">{{ task.priority }}</div>
```

And do your styling as such (assuming the output for the `task.priority` is high,medium,low. it looks like it would be according to your posted code)

```
.task_priority.high {color: red}
.task_priority.medium {color: yellow}
.task_priority.low {color: green}
```

Comment: this is awesome, just the kind of solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 96):

You can try this code above for conditional class in the html template

```
<element v-bind:class = "(condition)?'class_if_is_true':'else_class'"></element>
```

You may see the [official vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes) on this topic here.

Comment: Can anyone help me out in figuring whats the difference between using v-bind:class and :class ? Is it always checking the condition ? Like if the condition changes during some course of action in the page and the class should appear or disappear ? I believe v-bind is one way binding.

Comment: ":" is just a shorthand notation for v-bind, so there's no difference.  Whether it updates automatically is called "reactive" - 90% of the time it should "just work" but sometimes you'll have to play with computed properties vs. methods, etc.

Answer (score 73):

If you only need to add a class if condition is true, you can use:

```
<p v-bind:class="{ 'className' : priority === low}"></p>
```

or you can use shorthand notation by omitting `v-bind`

```
<p :class="{ 'className' : priority === low}"></p>
```

This way you don't have to care if condition turned out to be false.

Comment: What is the difference between binding it and just using :class?

Comment: @BigMoney: It's the same thing. More in the [official docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands) on this.

Answer (score 6):

You can try creating function and pass condition compare value to it

```
<span bind:class="BindOrderStatus(order.status)">{{order.status}}</span>
```

and write function like

```
 methods: {
    BindOrderStatus: function (status){
        if(status === "received")
        {
            return "badge badge-pill badge-primary pending-badge";
        }else if(status === "accepted" || status === "auto-accepted"){
            return "badge badge-pill badge-primary in-progress-badge"
        }.......etc conditions
```

}

this may be help you for complex conditions.