# simple class list toggle won't work in vue JS

Tags: jquery, vue.js, carousel

i have a carousel component with @next and @prev as buttons to move through it. Everytime I click on next, I want to toggle a div opacity on or off based on what slide number the user is on. I'm doing this by adding or deleting '.hide' class whenever the slide number turns 3. However it won't affect the visibility even though when i console log it - it shows that the class is gone.but in the Elements tab of console i can still see the class present in the element

here is some html

```
 <Carousel @next="next" @prev="prev">
      <CarouselSlide v-for="(slide, index) in slides" :key="slide" :index="index" :visibleSlide="visibleSlide">
         <div class="wrapper" :class="{ small: slide.makeSmall }">
            <video v-if='index === 0' autoplay controls>
               <source :src="slide.img1" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <img @click="storyboard" v-else :src="slide.img1" />
            <div class="counter hide">
               <p>{{ counter }} / 5</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </CarouselSlide>
   </Carousel>
```

here is some JS:

```
next() {
            if (this.visibleSlide >= this.slidesLen - 1) {
               this.visibleSlide = 0
               // console.log('visible:'+ this.visibleSlide, 'classes:' + document.querySelector('.counter').classList)
            } else {
               this.visibleSlide++
               console.log('visible:'+ this.visibleSlide, 'classes:' + document.querySelector('.counter').classList)
                 if (this.visibleSlide === 3) {
                  document.querySelector('.counter').classList.remove('hide')
                   console.log('true, ' + 'visible:'+ this.visibleSlide, 'classes:' + document.querySelector('.counter').classList)
                 } else {
                    document.querySelector('.counter').classList.add('hide')
                   console.log('false, ' + 'visible:'+ this.visibleSlide, 'classes:' + document.querySelector('.counter').classList)
                 }
            }
         },
         prev() {
            if (this.visibleSlide <= 0) {
               this.visibleSlide = this.slidesLen - 1
               console.log('visible:'+ this.visibleSlide, 'classes:' + document.querySelector('.counter').classList)
            } else {
               this.visibleSlide--
               console.log('visible:'+ this.visibleSlide, 'classes:' + document.querySelector('.counter').classList)
            }
         }
```

css

```
.counter {
      position: absolute;
      top: 5vh;
       opacity: 1;
   }
   
   .hide {
      opacity: 0;
   }
```

[image: an image of the console log]
[image: image of console element while on the slide]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a class conditionally in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52124081/how-to-add-a-class-conditionally-in-vue)

Comment: And [relevant docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes)